# pd.read_csv() keep number of decimals

Tags: python, pandas, csv, decimal, precision

I want to read a csv but it culls the number of decimals:

```py
fname = './sol/Pret-SB_A00DLR0_202205240635.pos'
skiprow = 0
with open(fname) as search:
    for i, line in enumerate(search):
        if "%  GPST" in line:
            skiprow = i
            break
df = pd.read_csv(fname, skiprows=skiprow, delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[[0, 1]])
df.head(2)
```

gives (first 2 rows, first five columns):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc07r.png)

the original data ([here](https://github.com/AdrianKriger/realTimePPP101/blob/main/static/sol/Pret-SB_A00DLR0_202205240635.pos)) has 8 decimal places in the 3rd and 4th columns. I need those.

`2211 196568.000  -25.732036008   28.282629130  1387.8994`
`2211 196569.000  -25.732032386   28.282633712  1389.4025`

How do I read a csv and retain the precision of the original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I read a csv and retain the precision of the original data?

You do have it, `pandas` simply limit number of digits for presentation purposes, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[28.282633712]})
print(df)
print(df.x[0])
print(df.x[0] == 28.282633712)
```

gives output

```
           x
0  28.282634
28.282633712
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of displayed digits to 8 like this:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.8f}".format
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'precision' parameter while reading csv

```
#read text file
pd.read_csv(f,float_precision='round_trip',delimiter = "\t")

#read csv
pd.read_csv(f,float_precision='round_trip')
```